# Trying to learn PHP prepared sql statements but im doing something wrong but im not sure what?

Tags: php, sql, prepared-statement

So i am trying to learn to use prepared statements in my queries as apposed to using the old mysql way but i'm not having much luck.

This is my code

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();

if($stmt->prepare("SELECT l.listingID, l.title, l.description, l.dateListed
FROM tbl_listings AS l
LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_type AS lt ON lt.listingID = l.listingID
LEFT JOIN tbl_type AS t ON t.typeID = lt.typeID
WHERE lt.typeID =?"))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$type);
    $type = 1;
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $description, $date);

    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo $id . ' - ' . $title . ' - ' . $description . ' - '.$date."<br />";    
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
else
{
    echo "error";
}
```

but it isnt printing anything out, i've run the query in my phpmyadmin with a 1 instead of the ? and it returns records so i know the query is correct, but im not sure im using the prepared bit correctly? can someone please advise me on where i might of gone wrong?

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the value to `$type` before binding it:

```
$type = 1;
$stmt->bind_param("i",$type);
```

Comment: thankyou for your reply, but it's still not echoing anything out, have i missed anything else? cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
$stmt = $db->stmt_init();

if($stmt->prepare("SELECT l.listingID, l.title, l.description, l.dateListed
FROM tbl_listings AS l
LEFT JOIN tbl_listing_type AS lt ON lt.listingID = l.listingID
LEFT JOIN tbl_type AS t ON t.typeID = lt.typeID
WHERE lt.typeID =?"))
{
    $type = 1;
    $stmt->bind_param("i",$type);
    $stmt->execute(); <-- Was missing this in my original code
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $title, $description, $date);

    while($stmt->fetch())
    {
        echo $id . ' - ' . $title . ' - ' . $description . ' - '. $date . "<br />"; 
    }
    $stmt->close();
}?>
```

got it working :) was missing a line of code that was needed to execute the query.